# How to Symbolicate iPhone App Crash Reports?

Tags: iphone, crash, symbolicatecrash

I retrieved the crash reports from iTunes Connect.

I referenced this site. 
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:MmxwdXObZLMJ:www.anoshkin.net/blog/2008/09/09/iphone-crash-logs/+iphone+crash+debig&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk

I tried....

```
$ symbolicatecrash report.crash MobileLines.app.dSYM > report-with-symbols.crash

Error in symbol file for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2 (7D11)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit<br><br>
Error in symbol file for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2 (7D11)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore<br><br>
Error in symbol file for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2 (7D11)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation<br><br>
Error in symbol file for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2 (7D11)/Symbols/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib<br><br>
Error in symbol file for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2 (7D11)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices<br><br>
Error in symbol file for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2 (7D11)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit<br><br>
Error in symbol file for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2 (7D11)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/MBXGLEngine.bundle/MBXGLEngine<br><br>
Error in symbol file for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2 (7D11)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox<br><br>
Error in symbol file for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2 (7D11)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
```

BUT... I didn't result. (find error message)
* This directory is located "bulid/Distribution-iphones"
* "MYGAME.app" file and "MYGAME.app.dSYM" file is located in same directory.

How can i do solve this problem. ?

Please help me :)

```
* Crash log  (carsh at thread 2 )
-----------------------------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 95230C2E-CD83-46BF-8DAE-F38BCD46B910<br>
Process:         MYGAMELite [303]<br>
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/4FB79BEC-2BF0-438B-82A8-C302CD52A85C/MYGAMELite.app/MYGAMELite<br>
Identifier:      MYGAMELite<br>
Version:         ??? (???)<br>
Code Type:       ARM (Native)<br>
Parent Process:  launchd [1]<br><br>

Date/Time:       2010-06-03 11:43:52.875 +0800<br>
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.1.2 (7D11)<br>
Report Version:  104<br><br>

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)<br>
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x03e3a002<br>
Crashed Thread:  2<br><br>

Thread 2 Crashed:<br>
0   AudioToolbox                   0x330d708c AU3DMixerEmbedded::SumInput16(unsigned long, AudioBufferList const&, AudioBufferList const&, unsigned long, float, unsigned long)
<br>1   AudioToolbox                   0x330d89a0 AU3DMixerEmbedded::Render(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long)
<br>2   AudioToolbox                   0x32fe6bb8 AUBase::DoRender(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, AudioBufferList&)
<br>3   AudioToolbox                   0x32fe6504 Render
<br>4   AudioToolbox                   0x330160b8 AUInputElement::PullInput(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, unsigned long)
<br>5   AudioToolbox                   0x33023fa8 AUInputFormatConverter2::InputProc(OpaqueAudioConverter*, unsigned long*, AudioBufferList*, AudioStreamPacketDescription**, void*)
<br>6   AudioToolbox                   0x32fe4b60 AudioConverterChain::CallInputProc(unsigned long)
<br>7   AudioToolbox                   0x32fe4a5c AudioConverterChain::FillBufferFromInputProc(unsigned long*, CABufferList*)
<br>8   AudioToolbox                   0x32fe4790 BufferedAudioConverter::GetInputBytes(unsigned long, unsigned long&, CABufferList const*&)
<br>9   AudioToolbox                   0x33023e30 CBRConverter::RenderOutput(CABufferList*, unsigned long, unsigned long&, AudioStreamPacketDescription*)
<br>10  AudioToolbox                   0x32fe4284 BufferedAudioConverter::FillBuffer(unsigned long&, AudioBufferList&, AudioStreamPacketDescription*)
<br>11  AudioToolbox                   0x32fe44a4 AudioConverterChain::RenderOutput(CABufferList*, unsigned long, unsigned long&, AudioStreamPacketDescription*)
<br>12  AudioToolbox                   0x32fe4284 BufferedAudioConverter::FillBuffer(unsigned long&, AudioBufferList&, AudioStreamPacketDescription*)
<br>13  AudioToolbox                   0x32fe3f10 AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer
<br>14  AudioToolbox                   0x33023844 AUConverterBase::RenderBus(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, unsigned long)
<br>15  AudioToolbox                   0x330ce928 AURemoteIO::RenderBus(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, unsigned long)
<br>16  AudioToolbox                   0x32fe6bb8 AUBase::DoRender(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, AudioBufferList&)
<br>17  AudioToolbox                   0x330cf308 AURemoteIO::PerformIO(int, unsigned int, unsigned int, AQTimeStamp const&, AQTimeStamp const&)
<br>18  AudioToolbox                   0x330cf4cc AURIOCallbackReceiver_PerformIOSync
<br>19  AudioToolbox                   0x330c76fc _XPerformIOSync
<br>20  AudioToolbox                   0x330181d8 mshMIGPerform
<br>21  AudioToolbox                   0x3309cec8 MSHMIGDispatchMessage
<br>22  AudioToolbox                   0x330d48d4 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*)
<br>23  AudioToolbox                   0x32fc9f20 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*)
<br>24  libSystem.B.dylib              0x30b5b7b0 _pthread_body

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to do symbolication, as the crash log has been symbolicated. "Symbolication" just turns all numerical addresses into meaningful function names.

In your case, it seems the audio file is messed up.

Comment: hmm.. I used *.caf file. Crash title is "AudioToolbox: AU3DMixerEmbedded::SumInput16" in iTunes crash report. I don't know this problem. -0-''